# Parametrizations of vector-valued functions

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

The two vector-valued functions $r_1$ and $r_2$ below give two different motions along the same path $C$.

$(a) \ $ Prove that the two functions do indeed parametrize the same curve.

$(b) \ $ How is the velocity, acceleration, $T$, $N$, and $B$ vectors, curvature and torsion different when an object is at the same location on $C_1$ and $C_2$?

$$
r_1(t) = (\cos t, \sin t, t) \\
r_2(t) = (\cos(u^3), \sin(u^3), u^3)
$$

*$u$ is used to so we aren't using same letter for the parameter in both $r_1$ and $r_2$.

Comment: You need to $\LaTeX$ify everything.

Comment: I do not know how to do that. I just need help understanding this question.

Comment: That's why I did it for you :P

Comment: Do you mean you want to project $r_2$ onto its first two coordinates and compare those curves?

Comment: Apparently the two vector valued functions are the same curve but give different motions along that same curve? How do I prove this?